# only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object, expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

Error

> only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object,
>   expressions can be used as a statement

```
**Code Line*
bool IsShiny() { get; set; }
```

Comment: `bool IsShiny { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

Remove **()**

bool IsShiny { get; set; }